# How to automate creating google driver folders via sdk?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to automate creation of google docs folder via sdk. is that possible via google driver sdk or google app scripting ?

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/

Comment: Yes its possible. Read the spi docs and come back with a specific coding question before it gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant docs, which describe the creation of folders, are at:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder

Creating a folder uses the same request as creating a file.  Assigning the correct MIME type to the file makes it act as a folder.